# Can't assign to columns that don't exist -- Using ARTool package

Tags: r, package, syntax-error

I'm producing a post-hoc test, using ARTool package, to see the difference among combinations of factors, but receive the below error

> Error: Can't assign to columns that don't exist.
> x Column `grade_levelbooks_quantile` doesn't exist.
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Below is the notes after traceback:

```
rlang::last_error()
<error/vctrs_error_subscript_oob>
Can't assign to columns that don't exist.
x Column `grade_levelbooks_quantile` doesn't exist.
Backtrace:
  1. emmeans::contrast(...)
  4. ARTool::artlm.con(m.art, "grade_level:books_quantile")
  5. ARTool:::artlm.con.internal(...)
  6. ARTool:::generate.art.concatenated.df(m.f.parsed, df, f.parsed)
  8. tibble:::`[[<-.tbl_df`(...)
  9. tibble:::vectbl_as_new_col_index(j, x, value, j_arg, value_arg)
 10. tibble:::vectbl_as_col_location(...)
 13. vctrs::vec_as_location(j, n, names)
 15. vctrs:::stop_subscript_oob(...)
 16. vctrs:::stop_subscript(...)
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.
```

The codes and the description of the data I used (I simplified the data due to sensitivity issues):

```
library(ARTool)
m.art = art(percentile_rank ~ grade_level + books_quantile + grade_level*books_quantile,
            data = read1)
art.con(m.art, "grade_level:books_quantile")
```

```
str(read1)
tibble [20,902 x 21] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ school_key               : chr [1:20902] "309" "296" "198" "189" ...
 $ school_year_key          : chr [1:20902] "2019" "2019" "2019" "2019" ...
 $ grade_level              : Factor w/ 9 levels "K","1","2","3",..: 1 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 ...
 $ percentile_rank          : num [1:20902] 43 97 84 23 27 5 84 6 1 21 ...
 $ discipline               : chr [1:20902] "Reading" "Reading" "Reading" "Reading" ...
 $ books_quantile           : Factor w/ 3 levels "Q4","IQR","Q1": 2 2 2 3 3 2 2 2 2 3 ...
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Maybe you could give a little more information on what kind of model you are trying to compute and include a reproducible example with sample data.  Please also have a look at the description of the formula argument in ```?art``` since there seems to be specific information on the inclusion of grouping terms. I have deleted my previous answer as it is not a feasible approach to tackle your problem.

Comment: I just noticed that your model includes no interactions. That makes it fairly meaningless to be wanting to compare combinations of two factors. If you want to do that, I'd think your model should include the interaction of those two factors. I'm thinking you need to spend a little time standing back and considering what exactly you are trying to accomplish, perhaps with some consulting help. Getting programs to run is no substitute for understanding what you're doing.

Comment: I think this is an issue with `tibbles`. (using the package from your previous question) `data(goggles, package="WRS2")` then either of these work `m.art = art(attractiveness ~ alcohol * gender, data = goggles) ; art.con(m.art, "alcohol:gender") ; art.con(m.art, ~alcohol*gender)`. But change the data to a `tibble` and rerun `goggles <- tibble::as_tibble(goggles) ; m.art = art(attractiveness ~ alcohol * gender, data = goggles) ;
art.con(m.art, "alcohol:gender") ; art.con(m.art, ~alcohol*gender)` gives similar errors as you get. So solution is make sure your data is a `data.frame`

Comment: Hmmm, interesting.

Comment: @user2957945: this works! thank you so much! can you paste your comment as an answer so I can mark it correct? Just in case other users can learn from this as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an issue with `tibbles`.
Using data from

```
data(goggles, package="WRS2")
```

then either of these work

```
m.art <- art(attractiveness ~ alcohol * gender, data = goggles) 
art.con(m.art, "alcohol:gender") 
art.con(m.art, ~alcohol*gender).
```

But if the data is a `tibble`, and rerun as before gives similar errors as you get.

```
goggles <- tibble::as_tibble(goggles) 
m.art <- art(attractiveness ~ alcohol * gender, data = goggles) 
art.con(m.art, "alcohol:gender") 
art.con(m.art, ~alcohol*gender)
```

So the solution is make sure your data is a `data.frame`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not absolutely sure, but I'd almost bet money that this is what you need:

```
art.con(m.art, c("grade_level", "books_quantile"))
```

Comment: It shows an error as below: Error in parse.art.con.formula(formula) : 
  Contrast must either be formula of form `~ X1*X2*X3` or term of form "X1:X2:X3")

Comment: Then I suggest trying `art.con(m.art, ~ grade_level * books_quantile)`

Comment: Plus it appears that the function doesn' work as documented, so you should report this to the developer of ARTool